# Is it safe to set variables as undefined in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, variables, coding-style, undefined

I like to have somewhat clean code:

```
var currentVar = aBigObject['Key1']['Key2']['Key3'];
generalValues.push(((!currentVar) ? 0 : currentVar));
```

The alternative (I think) is this:

```
if (!aBigObject['Key1']['Key2][Key3']) generalValues.push(0);
else generalValues.push(aBigObject['Key1']['Key2']['Key3']);
```

To me, the second is unnecessarily long and difficult to read. My question is, is it really safe/good practice to set a variable to something that can potentially be undefined?

Comment: ahouldn't the second example be push and not assigning?

Comment: You are correct, I edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The former to me is unnecessarily long and difficult to read. My question is, is it really safe/good practice to set a variable to something that can potentially be undefined?

It's perfectly *safe* in that it's not going to cause an error. It also means that you don't have to do all of those lookups again.

<s>Your alternative also seems to make little sense (and certainly **isn't** doing the same thing as your first code snippet), as it has a totally different behavior when `aBigObject['Key1']['Key2][Key3']` *isn't* falsey (assigning it to itself rather than pushing it on `generalValues`).</s> *(The edit to the question fixes this.)*

Your first example certainly has lots of unnecessary parens and can be written:

```
var currentVar = aBigObject['Key1']['Key2']['Key3'];
generalValues.push(!currentVar ? 0 : currentVar);
```

..and could possibly be better written as

```
generalValues.push(aBigObject['Key1']['Key2']['Key3'] || 0);
```

Your general point seems to be, "Why is the first snippet using `currentVar`?" And the answer is that property lookups are not free. So once you've done the lookup of `Key1` on `aBigObject`, and `Key2` on the result, and `Key3` on the result of *that*, you remember and reuse it rather than looking it up again. JavaScript objects are hashmaps, lookups are cheap but they aren't *free*. But in that *specific* case, you can do that another way (see above).

Comment: Sorry, I probably confused you with all the edits. Thanks for your help, I never knew the operator could be used like this.

Comment: @DillPixel: Yeah, the JavaScript `||` operator is [curiously powerful](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html). :-)

Answer (score 1):

Did you think about

```
var currentVar = aBigObject['Key1']['Key2']['Key3'] || 0;
generalValues.push(currentVar);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = {};
var b = a.foo;
```

This raises no errors, and sets a local variable `b` to a value of `undefined`. Nothing wrong with this.

However, things get crazy when you have nested properties, any level of which might be undefined.

```
a = {};
var b = a.foo.bar;
```

This example raises an exception. If any levle of the nesting can be absent, you need to test each level before drilling in.

```
a = {};
var b = a.foo && a.foo.bar;
```

---

In light of that, this code should push the deeply nested value, if it exists. And if it does not, push `0` instead.

```
generalValues.push(
  (
    aBigObject.Key1 &&
    aBigObject.Key1.Key2 &&
    aBigObject.Key1.Key2.Key3
  ) || 0
);
```

[Also... coffeescript is pretty cool](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3ageneralValues.push%28aBigObject.Key1?.Key2?.Key3%20%7C%7C%200%29)